# CHCSVPaser initialization in swift

Tags: ios, csv, swift

I'm developing iOS app that handles .csv file with CHCSVParser in swift.
in Objective-C, the initialization code goes like this.

```
CHCSVParser *p = [[CHCSVParser alloc] initWithContentsOfCSVFile:[inputFileURL path]
```

so in swift, I think it goes like

```
var p = CHCSVParser()
p.initWithContentsOfCSVFile(path)
```

but this code leads error "CHCSVParser does not have a member named 'initWithContentsOfCSVFile'".
BridgingHeader file works fine.

```
func parserDidBeginDocument(parser: CHCSVParser)
```

this delegation method successfully calld after p.parse() .

Does anyone please help me? What should I do?
Any advice appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift does an automatic conversion of Objective-C constructors and removes "initWith".  So in Swift, it is like this:

```
var p = CHCSVParser(contentsOfCSVURL: path)
```

In cases such as this, I recommend just typing the first part:

```
 var p = CHCSVParser(
```

an then taking a look at what Xcode autocomplete suggests.